# AWS Lambda updating object in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to update object from DynamoDB for hours and I can't get it to work. I'm using DocumentClient library and its method update(). When I tested it with API Gateway, I got this error:

```json
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property '_id' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:20:44)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);
    const id = event.listId;
                
    const params = {
        Key: {
            "ListId": id
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#name": "Name",
          "#shop": "Shop"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":name": event.listName,
            ":shop": {
                "_id": event.listShop._id,
                "name": event.listShop.name,
                "address": event.listShop.address,
                "city": event.listShop.city
            }
        },
        TableName: "mk-lists",
        UpdateExpression: "SET #name = :name, #shop = :shop"
    };
    
    dynamodb.update(params, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

I have Shop field in Lists table which is an object. Also, it is working when I test it in Lambda function. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my request body:

```json
{
  "listName": "Lista 13131",
  "listShop": {
    "_id": "933c836c-6868-4f56-a769-d59f5cbb231e",
    "name": "DIS",
    "address": "Podrinska 12",
    "city": "Uzice"
  }
}
```

Comment: Error says '_id' of undefined", how about confirming `event.listShop._id` really exists?

Comment: Please check what is the structure of the event object.

Comment: @shimo Check request body, I edited the post.

Comment: How are you invoking the function locally if it works in Lambda? That leads me to believe the problem isn't in the code you showed us but the invocation logic.

Comment: @Maurice I tried API Gateway test with the request body mentioned above and got that error.

Comment: And how does the event look like that your lambda gets from the API Gateway? My guess: your mapping is broken.

Comment: @Maurice If I understood you question, event looks just like request body but that listShop object is somehow undefined. Should I map that object in integration request?

Comment: What's the output of the console.log statement when the event comes from the API Gateway?

Comment: @Maurice I checked now again, it only has listId property but request body is not there after transformations

Comment: Update the output of `console.log(event);` to your question.

Comment: How are you calling this? Are the values in the request body, e.g.  `event.body`?  What is the *entire* output of `console.log(event)`.  You only posted the request body, but I suspect there's more to it.  For example, why aren't you getting an error  at `const id = event.listId;`. Based on the request body you've shared, the `listId` value isn't present.